# SQL Finding maximum value without top command

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a bases with a table:

```
-courses (key: name [ofthecourse], other attributes: year in which the course takes place)
```

I want to complete a query looking for an answer to the question:

On which year of study there is a maximum number of courses?

Normally, the query would be:

```
SELECT TOP 1 STUDYEAR 
FROM COURSES 
GROUP BY STUDYEAR 
ORDER BY COUNT(CNO) DESC;
```

But my question is, which query could complete this without using the `TOP 1` phrase?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inner query to get the maximum count. The only difference is though that it can return more than one record if they have the same count.

```
SELECT STUDYEAR 
FROM COURSES 
GROUP BY STUDYEAR 
HAVING COUNT(CNO) = (SELECT MAX(CNOCount) FROM 
        (SELECT COUNT(CNO) CNOCount
        FROM COURSES 
        GROUP BY STUDYEAR) X)
```

Another version with only one inner query:

```
SELECT STUDYEAR
FROM
    (SELECT STUDYEAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(CNO) DESC) RowNumber
    FROM COURSES 
    GROUP BY STUDYEAR) X
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. that's an error sql server comes up with :(